# Delete rows from table where at least one of the values is NULL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, common-table-expression, sql-delete

I have the following table in MS SQL Server:

```
RowID    PersonNum   Address1
  1      456         1 My street
  2      NULL        1 My street
  3      789         1 My street
  4      987         2 My street
  5      963         2 My street
  6      852         3 My street
  7      741         3 My street
  8      NULL        3 My street
```

I want to delete all rows that are in the same address where at least one of the personnum = NULL

So from the above, I would need to delete RowID's 1, 2, 3, 6, 7, 8.

RowID's 4 and 5 are ok as they have a PersonNum.  How do I achieve this in T SQL?  Is this possible using a CTE?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider this CTE solution:

```
with cte as (
    select 
        max(case when PersonNum is null then 1 end) over(partition by Address1) has_null
    from mytable
)
delete from cte where has_null = 1
```

The inner window `max()` checks if at least one record has an `PersonNum` that is `null` for the current `Address1`. The outer query deletes the flagged records.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `EXISTS` :

```
DELETE t
FROM table t
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 
              FROM table t1 
              WHERE t1.Address1 = t.Address1 AND t1.PersonNum IS NULL
             );
```